# Gimli That Axe Achievement Broken

Tags: steam, achievements, killing-floor

I'm having trouble getting the "Gimli That Axe" Achievement in [Killing Floor](http://store.steampowered.com/app/1250/). I bought [Dwarfs!?](http://store.steampowered.com/app/35480/) and got 40,000 gold to get the "Not A War hammer" achievement but I still didn't get the "Gimli That Axe" Achievement. Is this bugged or am I doing something wrong?

[image: Not A War hammer]

[image: Gimli That Axe]

Comment: Have you launched Killing Floor since you got the Dwarfs!? achievement?

Comment: @Keavon Yeah ( many times ) and played a round of Moonbase just in case.

Comment: You need to either buy the full version of Dwarfs on Steam or earn that achievement in the F2P version. If you own Dwarfs on Steam, you should already have the Axe.

Comment: @Rokk I do own Dwarfs and I do have the axe but it's the achievement I want as I'm trying to 100% the game.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee oops, my previous comment was wrong (guess I was still half asleep). Anyway, I think you need to explicitly download the F2P version of Dwarfs on Steam (even though you already have the full version), and earn the "Not A War hammer" achievement there. Owning Dwarfs on Steam does not unlock the achievement in Killing Floor, just a bad design choice by the Killing Floor developers.

Comment: [Is your steam profile set to public?](http://steamcommunity.com/app/1250/discussions/0/828937979196046458/)